# SVN post-commit hook isn't executing a command properly

Tags: svn, hook, sh, post-commit

I have a post-commit hook that works, but for some reason the following line of code is not working properly.  It creates my test file regardless of a fail.

```
!#/bin/sh

# force a failure
ifconfig -z 1>/dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   touch ~/Desktop/fail.txt
fi
```

The fail.txt file is created with or without that `-z`.  However, if I run this same code without executing via my post-commit hook, it works as it should.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook scripts execute in an empty environment, including an empty or severely limited `PATH`. As a result, your script most likely can't find/can't execute `ifconfig`.

Specify full paths to everything within your hook scripts.

Comment: Interestingly, it is able to determine what `~/` is and `touch` since the file is successfully created.  I'm going to try and add the full path to `ifconfig` and see what happens.

Comment: Note that I did say "severely limited `PATH`" - `~` may be part of that limited environment, and `touch` may be in that `PATH`.

Comment: Your suggestions worked!  Thanks for the quick answer.